# Reusing menu commands in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, command, menuitem

I have two menu contribution in my Eclipse plugin, that both show the same items. One is a dropdown in the toolbar, and another is a submenu in the right-click context menu.

Currently I have to add the items in each place separately, essentially repeating the same XML. I would like to avoid this.

The context menu is defined like this:

```xml
<menuContribution 
    locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?before=additions">
    <menu
       id="do.the.thing.context.menu"
       label="Do The Thing"
       ...
```

Then contributed to like this

```xml
<menuContribution
   locationURI="popup:do.the.thing.context.menu">
   <command
      commandId="the.first.command"
      ...
   <command
      commandId="the.second.command"
      ...
```

The toolbar item is defined like this:

```xml
<menuContribution
   locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
   <toolbar>
      <command
         commandId="the.first.command"
         style="pulldown">
      ...
```

Then contributed to like this:

```xml
<menuContribution
   locationURI="menu:the.first.command">
   <command
      commandId="the.first.command"
      ...
   <command
      commandId="the.second.command"
      ...
```

Note that the commands contributed in each case are identical. I would like to avoid duplicating the commands when contributing them to the different places.

How would I go about this? Is there a way to define a group/set of commands, then reference that in the `menuContribution`?

Is there a way to have the commands defined in one `<menu>` then reference that menu in both places?

Comment: You could do something with `dynamic` but that requires writing code.

Comment: That would probably end up being more complex than just repeating the commands in my simple case. I'm new to eclipse development, but it seems like there should be a mechanism to define groups of menu items and reuse them.

Comment: The old `actionSet` did this but it is now deprecated and should not be used. An Eclipse 4 'e4' RCP application can use Snippets to do this. But for a 3.x style plugin I don't know of anything.